# StaticInjectorError when using ngx-color-picker inside of MatDialog

Tags: angular

I have a color-picker component that uses ngx-color-picker directive. The component is in `entryComponents` of a module and is being used by MatDialog like this.

`openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(EntryComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      autoFocus: false
     },
    );
  }`

When I try to utilize some functionality of the ngx-color-picker inside of the color-picker component it throws `StaticInjectorError`.

When I use the component without the dialog, just in a simple component that isn't in `entryComponent` of a module - everything is okay.

To reproduce the issue please check this Stackblitz project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxkwq2

1. Press the `Open dialog` button
2. Click on the black rectangle
3. Check the console

Why could it happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide `MatDialog` in `AppComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers : [MatDialog]
})
```

Forked [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pclnbt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)